# preg_match ( PHP ) : report the *FIRST* conflicting character & HALT the operation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Supposedly my string is:

```
$a = 'abc-def";
```

i only want a-z in my string.

but i want to let the user know what "bad" character makes their string "bad".

i can do this:

```
$conflict = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9 .]/', '', $a);
echo "the conflict was: $conflict";
```

but if my string is huge.. let's say a document filled with lots of text.. then this code above would go through the entire document and show all the conflicting characters.

i would like it to STOP after it finds only 1 conflicting character.

that way less CPU / memory / resources are used.

in other words.

```
$a = 'abc-,def";
```

in this example it should stop and indicate the conflict is "-"

rather than report the conflict is : "-,"

because soon as it sees "-" it should stop looking anymore.

the goal is to not use too many resources.

**MORE INFO:**

the idea is to read a string from left to right (i suppose) and soon as a character is detected that does not obey the law of a-z and 0-9.. the process is to be terminated and the string that has been found is to be reported

Comment: Use the *limit* argument. See [PHP `preg_replace` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: "more info" extra has been added to the question for extra clarification.

Comment: use php function : strstr()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: So, what is wrong with `preg_match`? Check karthik's answer.

Comment: won't preg_match try to find all conflicting characters thus would this not be an indication that preg_match went through the whole string even if the string is a super large string from a document ? the concern is.. going through the whole string can be waste of resources. the desire is to stop and halt the operations soon as a conflict is detected. ( and report the character in question )

Comment: @SteadyState Afaik `preg_match` stops after the first match. On the contrary `preg_match_all` performs a global match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-z0-9]/i", $a, $match)) :
  echo "Conflict was: $match[0]";
```

**Logic:** Check for characters other than `a-z0-9` and if there is a match print the response.